# Checkbox checked and unchecked

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with checkboxes.
I'm trying to make a script that will on click of a checkbox to count all the checkboxes,
and each checked assign its value into array, and for unchecked assign 0 in the array.

For example, if we have five checkboxes last two are checked , the array will be: 0, 0, 0, 4, 5.
If you checked one more checkbox, (example first checkbox), then the result is: 1, 0, 0, 4, 5.
If you uncheck last two, the result is: 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.

This `array(1, 0, 0, 0, 0)` I send via Ajax in the database, so that when I open the same order,
the first checkboxe is already checked.
Thanks anyway for help.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="1">service 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="2">service 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="3">service 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="4">service 4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="5">service 5<br>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='service[]']").click(function(){
        var favorite = new Array();
        $.each($("input[name='service[]']:checked"), function(){            
            favorite.push($(this).val());
        });
        alert("My services are: " + favorite.join(", "));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w7p5ufy8/3/

Comment: Always post your code in your question please. And btw, in your fiddle the checkboxes have the name `name="servis[]"` but your jQuery looks for `$("input[name='mali_servis[]']")`

Comment: My fault, I apologize. It is corrected.

Comment: So what is the problem here? Seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("input[name='servis[]']").click(function(){
                var favorite = new Array();
                $.each($("input[name='servis[]']"), function(){            
                    if($(this).prop('checked')){
                    favorite.push($(this).val());
                    }else{
                    favorite.push(0);
                    }
                });
                console.log("My favourite sports are: " + favorite.join(", "));
 });
});
```

I change input[name="ali_servis[]"] and i add if in each for print the 0

Link JsFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/w7p5ufy8/5/

Comment: Thank you LTasty, I think that this will solve my problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the bulk of your existing code and just change one line if you remove the `:checked` from `$.each($("input[name='service[]']:checked")`.

Change:

```
favorite.push($(this).val());
```

to

```
favorite.push($(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).val() : 0);
```

or:

```
favorite.push(this.checked ? this.value : 0);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/w7p5ufy8/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$("input[name='service[]']").each(function(){            
    favorite.push( this.checked ? this.value : 0 );
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w7p5ufy8/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the values of only the checked checkboxes, use i[**s()**](https://api.jquery.com/is/) to check and conditionally add a 0

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='mali_servis[]']").click(function() {
    var favorite = new Array();
    $.each($("input[name='servis[]']"), function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        favorite.push($(this).val());
      } else {
        favorite.push(0);
      }
    });
    console.log("My favourite sports are: " + favorite.join(", "));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="servis[]" rel='1' value="1">servis 1
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="servis[]" rel='2' value="2">servis 2
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="servis[]" rel='3' value="3">servis 3
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="servis[]" rel='4' value="4">servis 4
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="servis[]" rel='5' value="5">servis 5
<br>
<input type="button" name="mali_servis[]" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<fieldset id="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="servis[]" rel='1' value="1">servis 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="servis[]" rel='2' value="2">servis 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="servis[]" rel='3' value="3">servis 3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="servis[]" rel='4' value="4">servis 4<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="servis[]" rel='5' value="5">servis 5<br>
</fieldset>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var checkboxes = $("#checkboxes input");
   checkboxes.on("click", function() {
        var favorite = new Array();
        checkboxes.each(function() { 
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {      
                favorite.push($(this).val());
            } else {
                favorite.push(0);
            }
        });
        alert("My favourite sports are: " + favorite.join(", "));
    });
});
```